# Laravel order by eagerly loaded column

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel eager loading to load data on the jquery datatables. My code looks like:

```
$columns = array(
    0 => 'company_name',
    1 => 'property_name',
    2 => 'amenity_review',
    3 => 'pricing_review',
    4 => 'sqft_offset_review',
    5 => 'created_at',
    6 => 'last_uploaded_at'
);

$totalData = Property::count();

$limit = $request->input('length');
$start = $request->input('start');
$order = $columns[$request->input('order.0.column')];
$dir = $request->input('order.0.dir');


$query = Property::with(['company','notices']);
$company_search = $request->columns[0]['search']['value'];
if(!empty($company_search)){
    $query->whereHas('company', function ($query) use($company_search) {
        $query->where('name','like',$company_search.'%');
    });
}

$property_search = $request->columns[1]['search']['value'];
if(!empty($property_search)){
    $query->where('properties.property_name','like',$property_search.'%');
}
if(!Auth::user()->hasRole('superAdmin')) {
    $query->where('company_id',Auth::user()->company_id);
}
$query->orderBy($order,$dir);


if($limit != '-1'){
    $records = $query->offset($start)->limit($limit);
}
$records = $query->get();
```

With this method I received error: `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'company_name' in 'order clause'` .

Next, I tried with following order condition:

```
if($order == 'company_name'){
    $query->orderBy('company.name',$dir);
}else{
    $query->orderBy($order,$dir);
}
```

However, it also returns similar error:  `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'company.name' in 'order clause'`

Next, I tried with `whereHas` condition:

```
if($order == 'company_name'){
    $order = 'name';
    $query->whereHas('company', function ($query) use($order,$dir) {
        $query->orderBy($order,$dir);
    });
}else{
    $query->orderBy($order,$dir);
}
```

But, in this case also, same issue.

For other table, I have handled this type of situation using DB query, however, in this particular case I need the notices as the nested results because I have looped it on the frontend. So, I need to go through eloquent.

Also, I have seen other's answer where people have suggested to order directly in model like:

```
    public function company()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Company')->orderBy('name');
    }
```

But, I don't want to order direclty on model because I don't want it to be ordered by name everytime. I want to leave it to default.

Also, on some other scenario, I saw people using `join` combining `with`, but I am not really impressed with using both `join` and `with` to load the same model.

What is the best way to solve my problem?

I have table like: **companies**: `id, name`, **properties**: `id, property_name, company_id`, **notices**: `title, slug, body, property_id`

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the `Property::with(['company','notices']);` will not join the companies or notices tables, but only fetch the data and attach it to the resulting `Collection`. Therefore, neither of the tables are part of the SQL query issued and so you cannot order it by any field in those tables.

What `Property::with(['company', 'notices'])->get()` does is basically issue three queries (depending on your relation setup and scopes, it might be different queries):

1. `SELECT * FROM properties ...`
2. `SELECT * FROM companies WHERE properties.id in (...)`
3. `SELECT * FROM notices WHERE properties.id in (...)`

What you tried in the sample code above is to add an `ORDER BY company_name` or later an `ORDER BY companies.name` to the first query. The query scope knows no `company_name` column within the `properties` table of course and no `companies` table to look for the `name` column. `company.name` will not work either because there is no `company` table, and even if there was one, it would not have been joined in the first query either.

The best solution for you from my point of view would be to sort the result Collection instead of ordering via SQL by replacing `$records = $query->get();` with `$records = $query->get()->sortBy($order, $dir);`, which is the most flexible way for your task.

For that to work, you would have to replace `'company_name'` with `'company.name'` in your `$columns` array.

The only other option I see is to `->join('companies', 'companies.id', 'properties.company_id')`, which will join the companies table to the first query.

#### Putting it all together

So, given that the rest of your code works as it should, this should do it:

```
$columns = [
    'company.name',
    'property_name',
    'amenity_review',
    'pricing_review',
    'sqft_offset_review',
    'created_at',
    'last_uploaded_at',
];

$totalData      = Property::count();
$limit          = $request->input('length');
$start          = $request->input('start');
$order          = $columns[$request->input('order.0.column')];
$dir            = $request->input('order.0.dir');
$query          = Property::with(['company', 'notices']);
$company_search = $request->columns[0]['search']['value'];
$property_search = $request->columns[1]['search']['value'];

if (!empty($company_search)) {
    $query->whereHas(
        'company', function ($query) use ($company_search) {
        $query->where('name', 'like', $company_search . '%');
    });
}

if (!empty($property_search)) {
    $query->where('properties.property_name', 'like', $property_search . '%');
}

if (!Auth::user()->hasRole('superAdmin')) {
    $query->where('company_id', Auth::user()->company_id);
}

if ($limit != '-1') {
    $records = $query->offset($start)->limit($limit);
}

$records = $query->get()->sortBy($order, $dir);
```

Comment: It does not work. Same error: `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'companies.name' in 'order clause'` I don't know how `companies` would work, because the result will be nested under the model name `company`. Isn't it?

Comment: $query is a Query Builder instance. Thus, you are writing a database query and need to use the table name when fully qualifying a column. If the Query Builder does not find companies.name, the companies table is not part of the query. What you can do is replacing `$records = $query->get();`with `$records = $query->get()->sortBy('Company.name')` and remove all the `orderBy` calls. This way you sort on the resulting Collection, which is less efficient but much more flexible.

Comment: I edited the answer to summarize it. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say. Could you please show the full working code with that join and also get that notices as the nested results.

Comment: Fully working is hard to achieve without having your application at hands. But I'll try...